# Aeron ArchiveException

Tags: aeron

- **I have a problem in loading cluster nodes on aeron . when node start to load logs from archive , the following error occurs:**

  io.aeron.exceptions.TimeoutException: ERROR - Archive connect timeout: step=3 subscription.uri=aeron:udp?term-length=65536|sparse=true|mtu=1408|endpoint=localhost:0
  at io.aeron.archive.client.AeronArchive$AsyncConnect.checkDeadline(AeronArchive.java:3470)
  at io.aeron.archive.client.AeronArchive$AsyncConnect.poll(AeronArchive.java:3342)
  at io.aeron.archive.ReplicationSession.connect(ReplicationSession.java:318)
  at io.aeron.archive.ReplicationSession.doWork(ReplicationSession.java:190)
  at io.aeron.archive.SessionWorker.doWork(SessionWorker.java:64)
  at io.aeron.archive.ArchiveConductor.doWork(ArchiveConductor.java:291)
  at io.aeron.archive.DedicatedModeArchiveConductor.doWork(DedicatedModeArchiveConductor.java:57)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.doWork(AgentRunner.java:304)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.workLoop(AgentRunner.java:296)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:162)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Consensus Module
  io.aeron.archive.client.ArchiveException: ERROR - ERROR - Archive connect timeout: step=3 subscription.uri=aeron:udp?term-length=65536|sparse=true|mtu=1408|endpoint=localhost:0
  at io.aeron.cluster.ConsensusModuleAgent.pollArchiveEvents(ConsensusModuleAgent.java:1937)
  at io.aeron.cluster.Election.followerLogReplication(Election.java:855)
  at io.aeron.cluster.Election.doWork(Election.java:195)
  at io.aeron.cluster.ConsensusModuleAgent.doWork(ConsensusModuleAgent.java:344)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.doWork(AgentRunner.java:304)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.workLoop(AgentRunner.java:296)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:162)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Archive
  io.aeron.exceptions.TimeoutException: ERROR - Archive connect timeout: step=3 subscription.uri=aeron:udp?term-length=65536|sparse=true|mtu=1408|endpoint=localhost:0
  at io.aeron.archive.client.AeronArchive$AsyncConnect.checkDeadline(AeronArchive.java:3470)
  at io.aeron.archive.client.AeronArchive$AsyncConnect.poll(AeronArchive.java:3342)
  at io.aeron.archive.ReplicationSession.connect(ReplicationSession.java:318)
  at io.aeron.archive.ReplicationSession.doWork(ReplicationSession.java:190)
  at io.aeron.archive.SessionWorker.doWork(SessionWorker.java:64)
  at io.aeron.archive.ArchiveConductor.doWork(ArchiveConductor.java:291)
  at io.aeron.archive.DedicatedModeArchiveConductor.doWork(DedicatedModeArchiveConductor.java:57)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.doWork(AgentRunner.java:304)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.workLoop(AgentRunner.java:296)
  at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:162)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cluster configuration is not correct for your test. `localhost` is not a valid endpoint when running cluster in a distributed environment for the archive replication channel.

The following link gives a sample of the configuration which needs set to establish a cluster.

https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/master/aeron-samples/src/main/java/io/aeron/samples/cluster/ClusterConfig.java

Comment: my cluster configuration is ok because it works fine in 3 nodes and i have a cluster with all details .but some times one node goes shutdown and when i want to start this node, archive exception happens.

Comment: Archive replication is only needed in some circumstances. From the URI you posted I can see the configuration is default and not set within your cluster.